# How to display events in calendar in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use a [calendar bootstap](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#demo)

How I can to display all events at calendar from AJAX?
I guess I need to fill array `events` from response AJAX?

My PHP:

```
     foreach($calendar as $val){
                    $this->outputData["calendar"][] = array(
                        "title" => $val->DetailToUsersName,
                        "type" => 'info',
                        "startsAt" => "Sat Jun 01 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0500",
                        "endsAt" => "Sat Jun 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0500",
                        "resizable" => true,
                        "incrementsBadgeTotal" => true,
                        "recursOn" => 'year'
                    );
                }

echo json_encode($this->outputData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to convert your AJAX response to the format defined in [bootstrap calendar docs](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#events-required-attribute):

```
$scope.events = [
  {
    title: 'My event title', // The title of the event
    type: 'info', // The type of the event (determines its color). Can be important, warning, info, inverse, success or special
    startsAt: new Date(2013,5,1,1), // A javascript date object for when the event starts
    endsAt: new Date(2014,8,26,15), // Optional - a javascript date object for when the event ends
    editable: false, // If edit-event-html is set and this field is explicitly set to false then dont make it editable.
    deletable: false, // If delete-event-html is set and this field is explicitly set to false then dont make it deleteable
    draggable: true, //Allow an event to be dragged and dropped
    resizable: true, //Allow an event to be resizable
    incrementsBadgeTotal: true, //If set to false then will not count towards the badge total amount on the month and year view
    recursOn: 'year', // If set the event will recur on the given period. Valid values are year or month
    cssClass: 'a-css-class-name' //A CSS class (or more, just separate with spaces) that will be added to the event when it is displayed on each view. Useful for marking an event as selected / active etc
  }
];
```

Comment: Create an array with these fields and do json_encode?

Comment: What is you ajax response returning?

Comment: Problem is my calendar is loaded before ajax

Comment: Just pass an empty array and populate it when the data is received. The calendar will update itself.

Comment: M y AJAX returns the following: `0:
endsAt: "Sat Jun 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0500"
incrementsBadgeTotal: true
recursOn: "year"
resizable: true
startsAt: "Sat Jun 01 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0500"
title: "Sb"
type: "info"`

Comment: Is it a json response?

Comment: Or short: `calendar: [{title: "Sb", type: "info",…}]`

Comment: Have you tried assigning `$scope.events = response.calendar` ?

Comment: I tried simply ` $scope.vm.events.push({title: 'New event', type: 'important', draggable: true, resizable: true}) It does now work`